# Difference between verifyNoMoreInteractions and verifyZeroInteractions in Mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

What is the difference between verifyNoMoreInteractions and verifyZeroInteractions in Mockito? Are the two same method?

Answer (score 9):

Apparently, `verifyZeroInteractions` it is the same as `verifyNoMoreInteractions` in 2.x:

```
public static void verifyZeroInteractions(Object... mocks) {
    MOCKITO_CORE.verifyNoMoreInteractions(mocks);
}
```

But I guess it is going to change in 3.x - https://github.com/mockito/mockito/issues/989